# Debug C# WinForms application crashing when using an extern C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winforms, crash

I am developing a WinForms application using .NET Framework 4.6.1 who execute continuosly a read routine from an extern DLL who communicates a PH sensor to read the PH and then do things depending of the actual PH.

My application is written in C#, the dll is written in C++. Everything seems to work fine, but randomly the communication from the phmeters and the program breaks, and more randomly the program just crashes, and I can see this written on the console:

```
Exception raised: System.FormatException in mscorlib.dll
Exception raised: System.FormatException in mscorlib.dll
The subprocess 0x3464 exited with code 0 (0x0)
Exception raised: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException in mscorlib.dll
The subprocess 0x3104 exited with code 0 (0x0)
The subprocess 0x363c exited with code 0 (0x0)
The application [...] exited with code 3221226356
```

Or this:

```
Exception raised: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException in mscorlib.dll
The subprocess 0x3004 exited with code 0 (0x0)
The subprocess 0x323c exited with code 0 (0x0)
Exception raised: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException in mscorlib.dll
The subprocess 0x3562 exited with code 0 (0x0)
The subprocess 0x363c exited with code 0 (0x0)
Exception raised: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException in mscorlib.dll
The subprocess 0x395d exited with code 0 (0x0)
The subprocess 0x391e exited with code 0 (0x0)
The application [...] exited with code 3221225485
```

Notice the crash code is different in each example.

I don't know if there's a relation between the raised exceptions before the crash, because I can see casual exceptions like this thrown in the console and the application kept running, but I'm near 100% sure the crash is due to some exception or error thrown in the external C++ dll, causing my program to just shut down.

I am using the external library like this for example:

```
[DllImport("portavo.dll", EntryPoint = "PortavoInitDll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void PortavoInitDll();
[DllImport("portavo.dll", EntryPoint = "PortavoSetTimingParam", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void PortavoSetTimingParam(ushort to, byte trial);

public static unsafe void Init()
{
    PortavoInitDll();
    PortavoSetTimingParam(500, 2);
}
```

There are others methods that I use in the same way.

Due to the randomness of the error (it can be running ok for 4 days, and then suddenly crashing, or run for 20h and crash), I don't know how to debug the error to try isolate where the problem is and think in a solution.

So,

- how can I try to get an idea of what's happening?
- I am using the external dll in a correct way? For what I've seen on the internet, this is the usual way of consuming external dlls.
- How can I run the functions of the external dll in other thread, so if it breaks, don't break my whole program?

My guess is for some reason the dll crashes, so the read function can't use the dll and causes the program to crash. If I could detect the crash, I could restart the dll with the Init function and probably the program would continue the execution.

Comment: If native DLL has  bug and corrupts memory, nothing will help, your application will crash also. What you can do is write another simple application (helper), which loads this DLL and makes requests. When you need DLL call, start Helper application. Between your Winform application and Helper application, you should establish out of proc connection and exchange via RCP calls.  Helper application can be simple Kestrel Web API project which accepts http requests or any other application which makes RPC communication straightforward.

Comment: Is the DLL in the same dir, or in path? The function declared with extern "C"?  Try to call an empty function, if it is still crashing then the problem is as described.

Comment: @SHR yes, the DLL is in the same directory. I don't get what do you mean to call an empty function, can you elaborate? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I try to get an idea of what's happening?

You rarely get much useful information from crashes in native code. Often just a SEHException or accessviolationexception.  You might be able to use tools like windbg to get more info, but I can provide little guidance on how to use it. And even if you got more information, you would not be able to do much with it without access to the source.

> I am using the external dll in a correct way? For what I've seen on the internet, this is the usual way of consuming external dlls.

That is impossible to tell without access to the documentation. But it looks fairly reasonable to me, there is not that much to go wrong if you are just passing a few numbers. Note that a well written library should document correct usage, and fail with a reasonable error message when used incorrectly. So if the documentation is unclear, and crashes are random, it is likely the fault of the library one way or another.

> How can I run the functions of the external dll in other thread, so if it breaks, don't break my whole program?

You can't protect your program with a thread, threads just do not provide that level of isolation.

You need to use a separate *process*. That will allow the OS to clean up after the crashing process, and you get the opportunity to restart it. You will need to use some form of Remote Procedure Call (RPC) or other kind of Inter Process Communication (IPC) to communicate between the processes. This might be something like a HTTP or gRPC server, or some message queue like  MQTT. There are ton of different technologies and protocols that can be used for this.

You should probably also report the problem to the vendor of the library. Its may not a great chance that it will fix the problem, but you might get lucky.

Comment: Yeah, I've already contacted the vendor and they ensure that my code is ok and they don't know why we are getting these crashes.